# Can´t use navigation && props in React-Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on a React-Native Project and found an issue..

Everything is working fine except my HomeStackScreen, i want to pass data via props, but also want to navigate to open a drawer

```
const HomeStackScreen = (props, navigation) => (


  console.log("HOME STACK:   " + props.studentData),

  <HomeStack.Navigator headerMode="screen" studentData={props.studentData}>
    <HomeStack.Screen name = "Home" children={() => <HomeScreen studentData={props.studentData} />} options={{
      title:'Home',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#e67e22',
        

      },
      headerRight: () => (
        <Icon.Button name="build" size={30} 
        backgroundColor="#e67e22" color="white" paddingLeft= {15} onPress= {() => navigation.
        openDrawer()}></Icon.Button>
      )
    }}/>
  </HomeStack.Navigator>

);
```

Here is my code, but when I write

```
const HomeStackScreen = (props) => (
```

or

```
const HomeStackScreen = ({navigation}) => (
```

everything works, but when I want to use both I get an error, telling me one of them is not a function

Comment: Does props.studentData work ?

Comment: yes props.studenData works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use them like this :

```
const HomeStackScreen = (props) => {
  const {navigation,studentData} =  props ;
  return ...

}
```

Comment: thx a lot! it works - I used your code and restarted

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: coming from Angular, very new to React (Native) - still having some troubles with props, state etc.

Comment: Good job, wish you the best.

Answer (score 1):

Pass props as an object and:

```
const HomeStackScreen = ({navigation, studentData}) => (


  console.log("HOME STACK:   " + studentData),

  <HomeStack.Navigator headerMode="screen" >
    <HomeStack.Screen name = "Home" children={() => <HomeScreen studentData={studentData} />} options={{
      title:'Home',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#e67e22',
        
      },
      headerRight: () => (
        <Icon.Button name="build" size={30} 
        backgroundColor="#e67e22" color="white" paddingLeft= {15} onPress= {() => navigation.
        openDrawer()}></Icon.Button>
      )
    }}/>
  </HomeStack.Navigator>

);
```